# Apache Virtual Host Configuration Doubts

Tags: apache, virtualization, virtualhost

I was configuring Apache Name based virtual hosts for my websites. I have two application X and Y. X is running on physical machine M1 and Y is on physical machine M2 (in tomcat). Apache is also configured on M1. I am using below format,

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mydomain.com
  ProxyPass /X ajp://localhost:8080/X
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mydomain.com
  ProxyPass /Y ajp://M2:8080/Y
</VirtualHost>
```

This is working fine. To understand what exactly is going under the hood, I have few questions,

> 1. Since there are two machines (M1 and M2) in this entire story, which IP I need to to mention as NameVirtualHost directive and what
>      this field really used for? If this is M1's IP, then why we need to
>      mention this explicitly since we are doing the entire configuration on
>      M1 itself (we assumed, Apache is installed on M1)
> 2. What is the need of mentioning IP address again in VirtualHost tag?
> 3. Is there any chance when two VirtaulHost tag will contain different IPs?

Thanks in advance..:)

Comment: Anybody...any update?